# Why choose a static class over a singleton implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, static, singleton

The Static Vs. Singleton question has been discussed before many times in SO.
However, all the answers pointed out the many advantages of a singleton.

My question is - what are the advantages of a static class over a singleton?
Why not simply choose a singleton every time?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541/when-should-you-use-the-singleton-pattern-instead-of-a-static-class

Comment: Nope, that question is the exact opposite to my question! Please read the two questions again.

Comment: Thats an odd response considering the answer you accepted actually emphasises the potential disadvantages of using static classes.

Comment: refer this. might be useful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31503153/3805988

Answer (score 43):

Static class is a technical tool in your box - basically a language feature.

Singleton is an architectural concept.

You may use a static class as a means to implement the singleton concept. Or you may use some other approach.

With static classes in C# there are two *potential* dangers if you're not careful.

- The requested resources will not be freed until the end of application life
- The values of static variables are shared within an application. Especially bad for ASP.NET applications, because these values will then be shared between all users of a site residing in a particular Application Domain.

Answer (score 23):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx)

> Static classes and class members are used to create data and functions
>   that can be accessed without creating an instance of the class. Static
>   class members can be used to separate data and behavior that is
>   independent of any object identity: the data and functions do not
>   change regardless of what happens to the object. Static classes can be
>   used when there is no data or behavior in the class that depends on
>   object identity.

A key point is that static classes `do not require an instance reference`. Also note that static classes are specifically enabled by the language and compiler.

Singleton classes are just user coded classes implementing the [Singleton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZaXM67fxbs) design pattern. Singleton purpose is to `restrict instantiation of an class to a single instance`.

If you coded every static class as a singleton you'd have to instantiate the class every time you used it.

i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine('Hello World');
```

would become

```
Console c = Console.getInstance();
c.WriteLine('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd say they're both (generally) poor solutions. There are a few use cases for static classes, primarily simple utility ones (Extension Methods in C# 3.0 come to mind). With any degree of complexity, though, testability issues start cropping up.

Say class A depends on static class B. You want to test class A in isolation. That's hard.

So you go with a Singleton. You have the same problem - class A depends on singleton B. You can't test class A in isolation.

When class B has other dependencies (such as hitting a database) or is mutable (other classes can change its global state), the problem is exacerbated.

IoC ([Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) container libraries are one solution to this problem; they let you define Plain Old Classes as having a long lifespan. When combined with a mocking library, they can make your code very testable.

Comment: +1 static classes and singletons are globally accessible. Global is evil :-)

Answer (score 6):

Static classes are much easier to implement - I have seen many attempts at thread-safe singletons in C# that employs naive locking schemes instead of depending on the run-time's guaranteed one-time initialization of static fields (optionally inside a nested class to delay instantiation).

Other than that, I think singletons are great if you need to pass around a reference to an object that implements a specific interface, when that 'implemention' should be singleton, something which you cannot do with static classes.

Answer (score 2):

One consideration I don't see mentioned is that preferring a solution using an instance of a class (singletons, or their DI equivalent) allows you to provide a class on which other users of your code may define extension methods -- since extension methods only work with non-static classes as the `this` parameter.  In other words, if you have a line like:

```
GlobalSettings.SomeMethod();
```

Then syntactically the only thing that can be accessed via `GlobalSettings` are members you provide.  In contrast, if `GlobalSettings` is an instance (singleton or otherwise) then consumers may add their own extensions to `GlobalSettings` that they would be unable to do otherwise:

```
application.GlobalSettings.CustomSomethingOrOther();
```

or

```
GlobalSettings.Instance.CustomSomethingOrOther();
```

Answer (score 1):

The question leads to the need for a better understanding of what you are implementing, how it suppose to work, and what it should be capable of.

Let's say, you need some kind of Manager class that handles your object's in a particular way. Singleton requires a bit more work, but in return, it gives you the ability to treat your manager by its interface (IManager) rather than the strict name. With a static class, you obviously losing the inheritance, interfaces, and the ability to swap or reset the object by just re-instantiating it rather than manually zeroing all the static variables, but it also gets you rid of a bit of extra work in case if your static object is kept simple.

There are more extra details if you go deeper, but in general 99% of times, it's just a question of personal preference or your team's coding guidelines.