# Static methods vs singletons

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why choose a static class over a singleton implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321352/why-choose-a-static-class-over-a-singleton-implementation)

Static methods vs singletons.
Could it be determined choice here?
What are conditions in which one of these approaches is definetely more suitable then other?

Comment: are you talking about static singleton patter vs singleton patters ?

Comment: I'm talking about utility class with static methods vs singleton with methods.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=static+singleton+[c%23]

Comment: you have more than ten questions without an accepted answer. ;)

Comment: I would use an `enum` with one instance as singleton if you need to implement an interface. Otherwise, I would use an `enum` with no instances and static methods as a Utility class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods follow the "low coupling and high coherence"-rule more than singletons do. (As long as their implementations don't rely on static member variables.)

Answer (score 2):

If the static methods solve the same problem as the singleton, then why complicate and write a singleton?

Otherwise, why choose something that solves the wrong problem?